# Business won't show up on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm having problems with showing a business on Google Maps.

I've created the Google+ and business page. I've updated all the info and the Google verification code so the business **is verified** (I've verified it 3 weeks ago).

The problem is when I search for my business on Google Maps, it displays nothing. It won't show the marker nor the information on the maps.

But when I go to *Settings* → *Profile* → *This page is connected to Google Maps. View | Learn more* and click **View**, it displays everything good.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be for a number of reasons:

1. There are specific guidelines for this; [check them](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177?ref_topic=4540086) and make sure everything is okay.
2. Sometimes it can take more than 3 weeks; wait a little longer.
3. Every Google Place must have a street address, so if you didn't mention it, this is the problem.
4. [Google My Business](http://www.google.com/business/befound.html#get-on-the-map) is the new dashboard where you manage your business (previously you need to do it in Google+ page and Google Places, but now it's all from their [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.vega) (or [site](http://www.google.com/business/befound.html#get-on-the-map)), so you can check there that everything is good.
5. If everything is good, and you waited a couple more weeks, [contact them](https://support.google.com/business/?from=lbc&rd=1#topic=4540086).

Comment: I think that I just had to wait a little longer because now it's showing fine :)