# Google Maps shows wrong name

Tags: google-maps

Recently I posted a question [Business won't show up on Google Maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70487/business-wont-show-up-on-google-maps). It turned that I had to wait a bit longer for Google to put my business on its maps.

Now I have a new problem - the name of the business is wrong.

The business contains the word "**square**" in its name, but the name near the pin on Google Maps shows "**squre**" (notice the letter "**a**" is missing), but when I click on my business, the information in the top left box are correct.

Is there a way for me to manually fix this, or do I have to write a report to Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the "new" Google Maps, here's how you can report and correct an entry.

1. Find the business on the map. Click its name/icon to drop a marker

[image: marker]

2. Click the help button in the lower right (a question mark inside a speech bubble

[image: Google Maps help menu]

3. Choose "report a data problem"

[image: "Report a problem" menu]

4. Click the name and make your correction

[image: making corrections]

If it's the icon on the map rather than the information in the pop-up, click on "Report something else" and proceed from there.

(If you've already "claimed" your business on the map, the process for reporting corrections is probably different.)

Comment: I did what you said and the name corrected within 12 hours. That was fast :)
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Vucko: Well, I would hope that the people reviewing these can recognize a misspelling pretty quick.